# Can I change words in a URL served by an Apache server?

Tags: apache

I have a url that looks something like: http://host.name.com/old/ and I want the new URL to be http://host.name.com/new/.

Is this easily done in Apache? I can't modify every link that has /old/ and I need the webserver to do this for me automatically.

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect task for [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html). Especially see [Redirecting and Remapping with `mod_rewrite`)](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/remapping.html).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/old/$ /new/ [PT]
```

<sub>(not tested, wasn't clear if you need internal or external URL rewriting, may cause temporary blindess and abdominal distension, etc.)</sub>